# FreeBSD Local Smart Card Auth Only

Tags: security, freebsd

I'm trying to figure out how to configure a FreeBSD CLI installation to only allow authentication via X.509 certificates. I'm not talking about SSH, I'm talking about locally in front of the server. I'd ideally like to completely remove passwords from the entire infrastructure with the exception of a password on the key used for login, which will only exist in one place. I've reviewed the security manual on the FreeBSD website as well as the manage for `LOGIN.CONF` and can't find what I'm looking for. Any ideas?